# Why is my code looping itself on first item

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping

Im making a code that scrapes a website for lyrics on a bunch of artists and saves the lyrics as .txt files in a directories named after their respective albums.

But after my program has finished the first artist, it keeps looping the same artist. Why?

Code:

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import time
os.chdir("D:/Folder")

import urllib.request

if os.path.isfile('hist'):    
#creating history file (r for read), so that we get a link for every song we have scaped, so that we don't scrape it again (we need to scrape each file only once)
    with open('hist', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        history = file.read().split()
else:
    history=[]
    
artists=["lil wayne","bob dylan","beyonce"]
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
urlhome = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com/"
frontpage = urllib.request.urlretrieve(urlhome,"data/frontpage")
front = open("data/frontpage", encoding="utf-8").read()
soupfront = BeautifulSoup(front,features="lxml")

for artist in artists:
    if not os.path.exists("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)):
        os.mkdir("D:/Folder/"+str(artist))
    link=urlhome+str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+")
    getartist=urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    artistpage = BeautifulSoup(getartist,features="lxml")
    albums=artistpage.findAll("a", attrs={"class":"lf-link lf-link--secondary"})

    for album in albums:
        if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:
            albumurl = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com"+album["href"]
            albumpage = urllib.request.urlopen(albumurl)
            albumsoup = BeautifulSoup(albumpage,features="lxml")
            albumyear = albumsoup.find("div",attrs={"class":"lf-album__meta-item"}).text.strip()[-6:]
            
            albumname = album.text.strip()+" "+albumyear
        if not os.path.exists("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)+"/"+albumname):
            os.mkdir("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)+"/"+albumname)
        songs = albumsoup.findAll("a",href=True,attrs={"class":"lf-link lf-link--secondary"})
        
        for song in songs:
            if song['href'] in history:
                print('Skipping', song['href'], '-already on drive')
                continue #if it's already scraped, it continues to the next song

            time.sleep(3)
            if "/album/" not in song["href"]:
                songurl = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com"+song["href"]
                songpage = urllib.request.urlopen(songurl)
                songsoup = BeautifulSoup(songpage,features="lxml")
                songname = songsoup.find("span",attrs={"class":"item-header-color"}).text[:-7]
                lyrics = songsoup.find("div",attrs={"id":"content"})
                fixedlyrics = lyrics.text.strip()
                lyricfile = open(artist+"/"+albumname+"/"+(songname)+".txt","w")
                lyricfile.write(fixedlyrics)
                with open('hist', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file: #a for append
                    file.write(song['href'] + '\n')
                print("parsing "+str(songname))
```

Comment: Well, why do you use `artist[0]` instead of just `artist` since you are looping on a list. Add some prints inside your loop to see what you are actually doing.

Comment: the `artist[0]` is to get the first letter of the artist name to be used in the link

Comment: @anonymous the URL for each artist is lyricfreak.com/x/artist where x is the first letter in the artist name, therefore artist[0] like chitown88 says.

Comment: Why do you think it keeps looping on the same artist name? Maybe print the `artist` in your for loop.

Comment: @doctorlove Its not looping the same name, its just looping the last album over and over again, and I dont know why thats why i ask. The whole code works fine for creating all the lyric files for the first artist in ```artists=[]``` but once its finished it doesnt go on to the next one but rather loops in a weird way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block of code after:

```
if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:
            albumurl = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com"+album["href"]
            albumpage = urllib.request.urlopen(albumurl)
            albumsoup = BeautifulSoup(albumpage,features="lxml")
            albumyear = albumsoup.find("div",attrs={"class":"lf-album__meta-item"}).text.strip()[-6:]
            
            albumname = album.text.strip()+" "+albumyear
```

Needs to be indented to be included with in that condition statement. Other wise, it just skips that little block and then just repeats everything on the last `albumurl` stored string.

**Full Code:**

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import time
os.chdir("D:/Folder")

import urllib.request

if os.path.isfile('hist'):    
#creating history file (r for read), so that we get a link for every song we have scaped, so that we don't scrape it again (we need to scrape each file only once)
    with open('hist', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        history = file.read().split()
else:
    history=[]
    
artists=["lil wayne","bob dylan","beyonce"]
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
urlhome = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com/"
frontpage = urllib.request.urlretrieve(urlhome,"data/frontpage")
front = open("data/frontpage", encoding="utf-8").read()
soupfront = BeautifulSoup(front,features="lxml")

for artist in artists:
    if not os.path.exists("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)):
        os.mkdir("D:/Folder/"+str(artist))
    link=urlhome+str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+")
    getartist=urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    artistpage = BeautifulSoup(getartist,features="lxml")
    albums=artistpage.findAll("a", attrs={"class":"lf-link lf-link--secondary"})

    for album in albums:
        if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:
            albumurl = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com"+album["href"]
            albumpage = urllib.request.urlopen(albumurl)
            albumsoup = BeautifulSoup(albumpage,features="lxml")
            albumyear = albumsoup.find("div",attrs={"class":"lf-album__meta-item"}).text.strip()[-6:]
            
            albumname = album.text.strip()+" "+albumyear
        
            if not os.path.exists("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)+"/"+albumname):              #<-- INDENT REST OF CODE
                os.mkdir("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)+"/"+albumname)
            songs = albumsoup.findAll("a",href=True,attrs={"class":"lf-link lf-link--secondary"})
            
            for song in songs:
                if song['href'] in history:
                    print('Skipping', song['href'], '-already on drive')
                    continue #if it's already scraped, it continues to the next song
    
                time.sleep(3)
                if "/album/" not in song["href"]:
                    songurl = "https://www.lyricsfreak.com"+song["href"]
                    songpage = urllib.request.urlopen(songurl)
                    songsoup = BeautifulSoup(songpage,features="lxml")
                    songname = songsoup.find("span",attrs={"class":"item-header-color"}).text[:-7]
                    lyrics = songsoup.find("div",attrs={"id":"content"})
                    fixedlyrics = lyrics.text.strip()
                    lyricfile = open(artist+"/"+albumname+"/"+(songname)+".txt","w")
                    lyricfile.write(fixedlyrics)
                    with open('hist', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file: #a for append
                        file.write(song['href'] + '\n')
                    print("parsing "+str(songname))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Even though I learned a new thing from your code, namely the fact that you can refer to the 1st element with a specific class with ```{'lf-list js-sort-table'})[1]"```, it did not solve my issue here. I actually already had a fix for the related albums in line 40 with ```if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:``` , but yours is definitely better. However my program still loops on its head either doing the last album over and over again if its the first time running the program, or looping the skip (line 51-54) for the last album :/

Comment: Ok. I’ll take another look tomorrow. I thought it was fixed.

Comment: so the code you used above still loops on the last album?

Comment: Yes after it has finished, it will for some reason loop over the last album again and again. If i dont remove the files and run the code again, it will get stuck looping over the "skipping x song" where x is also the songs on the last album it added. I dont think the problem is the specific album or artist, because changing the order of the artists in the list didnt fix it. But other than that I have no idea...

Comment: ok. was just an indent issue. after `if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:` that all needs to be within the block. but you have a new block at `if not os.path.exists("D:/Folder/"+str(artist)+"/"+albumname):`. So it was just looping without changing anything under `if str(artist[0])+"/"+artist.replace(" ","+") in album["href"]:`

Comment: @Youngun, give it a try now. I think that did it

Comment: 88 Hey chief, So the whole code runs through smoothly now, however at the end it gives me the errorcode: 
```python
albumdate = albumsoup.find("div",attrs={"class":"lf-album__meta-item"}).text.strip()[-6:]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'```

Can you perhaps figure it out? The result is that for the very last song it only makes a .txt file but doesnt write anything in it.

Comment: yup. It means on the last song, it doesnt have a tag of `<div>` with atrribute `class":"lf-album__meta-item"` . `albumsoup.find("div",attrs={"class":"lf-album__meta-item"})` is returning `None`

Comment: but it does, doesnt it? I mean its on the same album as previous songs and there definitely is this specific class and div on the last Beyoncé album. Shouldnt the error come when it does the album stuff and not after checking the last song? I mean after the last song loop it should be totally finished essentially?

Comment: Well, one of those extra links in the bottom is `https://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/beyonce+jay+z/`. so your logic in the code lets that pass. That takes you to `The Carters` lyrics...whcih doesn't contain an album title or year. So no meta data there.

Comment: You are my freakin hero! Thank you so much, it makes total sense and is fixed now